# Commuting analogue of the cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real inner product space. I am fairly sure that the following operation cannot exist, and would like a nice conceptual explanaition for its impossibility.

> **Question:** Can there exist a product $(x,y) \mapsto xy : V \times V \to V$ satisfying
>
> - Bilinearity
> - Commutativity
> - Orthogonality meaning $xy$ is perpindicular to $x$ (and $y$ too, by commutativity) for all $x,y \in V$?

**Added:** As was pointed out in the comments, I want to exclude the zero product.

**My thoughts:** I didn't think of anything too useful, just that the orthogonality gives us that for fixed $x$, the map $y \mapsto xy$ is an antisymmetric transformation. So we have the identity $(xy,z) = -(y,xz)$. This lets us play around a bit, e.g.
$$(xy,z) = (yx,z) = -(x,yz) = -(x,zy) = \ldots$$
but I didn't get anywhere this way.

Comment: The trivial product $V \times V \ni (x,y) \mapsto 0 \in V$ fits the bill. You might want to reformulate the question... (perhaps add some extra restriction?)

Comment: To exclude the zero product, say $xy=0$ \iff either $x=0,y=0$ or $x=\lambda y$ for some non-zero $\lambda$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: For now I just want to focus on the stronger statement: does there exist such a product other than the trivial one where $xy = 0$ for all $x,y$?

Comment: The wedge product maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim that the only such product is the trivial product.

Observe that the datum of a bilinear form $m : V \times V \to V$ is equivalent to the datum of a tensor $\omega \in (V^\ast)^{\otimes 3}$ via
$$
 \forall x, y, z \in V, \quad \omega(x,y,z) = \langle x,m(y,z) \rangle.
$$
Then $m$ is commutative if and only if $\omega \in V^\ast \otimes (S^2 V^\ast)$ and satisfies the orthogonality condition if and only if $\omega \in (\wedge^2 V^\ast) \otimes V^\ast$, so that $m$ is an operation of the desired form if and only if
$$
 \omega \in V^\ast \otimes (S^2 V^\ast) \cap (\wedge^2 V^\ast) \otimes V^\ast.
$$
But now, suppose we have such a tensor $\omega$. Then for any $x$, $y$, $z \in V$,
$$
 \omega(x,y,z) = -\omega(y,x,z) = -\omega(y,z,x) = \omega(z,y,x) = \omega(z,x,y) = -\omega(x,z,y) = -\omega(x,y,z),
$$
so that $\omega(x,y,z) = 0$.

If you like, the underlying reason why any product of the desired form must be zero is that the subspaces $V^\ast \otimes (S^2 V^\ast)$ (corresponding to symmetry) and $(\wedge^2 V^\ast) \otimes V^\ast$ (corresponding to the orthogonality condition) of $(V^\ast)^{\otimes 3}$ have trivial intersection, as a result of the behaviour of the canonical representation of the permutation group $\mathfrak{S}_3$ on $(V^\ast)^{\otimes 3}$ by permutation of indices. Explicitly, since $V^\ast \otimes (S^2 V^\ast)$ is the $+1$ eigenspace of the permutation $(2\,3) \in \mathfrak{S}_3$ and $(\wedge^2 V^\ast) \otimes V^\ast$ is the $-1$ eigenspace of the permutation $(1\,2) \in \mathfrak{S}_3$, it follows that $V^\ast \otimes (S^2 V^\ast) \cap (\wedge^2 V^\ast) \otimes V^\ast$ is in the $-1$ eigenspace of
$$
 (2\,3)(1\,2)(2\,3)(1\,2)(2\,3)(1\,2) = e \in \mathfrak{S}_3,
$$
which, of course, is trivial.

Comment: Thanks! In fact my own ad hoc calculations weren't so far off..... I gave up too soon! I will wait a bit to accept your answer, so that it gets more visibility.

Comment: We can also, of course, do this without introducing tensor products--though I appreciate the connection with representation theory.  By the commutativity, we don't need to pay attention to how we group terms on either side of the inner product. Moving a term across the inner product gives a minus sign. So...for any $x,y,z$ we get $(xy,z) = -(x,yz)=(xz,y)=-(z,xy)$ which shows $(xy,z)=0$ and so, $z$ being arbitrary, $xy=0$ as desired.